# Checking aliveness of a long running Python process

Tags: python, monitoring

How can I check the aliveness of a Python process (not a 24*7 running server process)? I am thinking to build following solution,

Send a heartbeat from the python process on a regular basis to a file. Externally we can deploy a system that can check if the entry (last updated time) is there in a file or not, if not then consider process to be dead.

**Questions:**

1. Is there some better solution then this?
2. Are there some existing solutions for sending heartbeat from a python process?

Comment: Sorry but asking for library recommendations is strictly off-topic on SO

Comment: I assume you want to monitor the process on a different server to the one you are running your monitoring code on? Or could they run on the same machine?

Comment: @Tony, yes Python process is running on a different machine.

Comment: @Tony I was thinking of two approaches, 1. I can use some external monitoring system like supervisord that monitors a process using pid of a process, 2. Process itself sends a heartbeat that I am alive.

Comment: If the process is not supposed to run 24/7 you would have to control when the supervisor starts/stops as well. I'd go for option 2 and then monitor the heartbeat using another process on a different server.

Answer (score 2):

What about RPC? Using `rpyc` or `pyro`? You could expose a single remote method named `get_heartbeat()` which would fetch a timestamp. If the method locks, errors or the value is old you then signal that something is wrong. No need for file checking and any of that just a simple memory value.

Links:

https://pyro4.readthedocs.io

https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Below example using `rpyc`:

```
import rpyc

class MyService(rpyc.Service):
    heartbeat = 0 # Here you can insert timestamp from different object, update it or even leave a reference to an object that has the heartbeat variable 
    def on_connect(self, conn):
        # code that runs when a connection is created
        # (to init the service, if needed)
        pass

    def on_disconnect(self, conn):
        # code that runs after the connection has already closed
        # (to finalize the service, if needed)
        pass

    def exposed_get_heartbeat(self): # this is an exposed method
        return self.heartbeat

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer
    t = ThreadedServer(MyService, port=18861)
    t.start()
```

And the control scipt

```
import rpyc
c = rpyc.connect("localhost", 18861)
while True:
   try:
        c.root.get_heartbeat()
        sleep(5)
   except Exception:
        pass
        #Error logic goes here
```

Comment: This approach might not work for my use-case. Reason#1 : My python processes are BatchJobs, they are short lived processes (but can be long running). Reason#2 : They are scheduled to run on a cluster host by mesos scheduler (http://mesos.apache.org/) hence keeping track of PIDs is really not feasible.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal That wouldn't be a problem in `pyro` you have something like DNS server where every remote service registers itself with it. Those can be on different physical machines they just need to be network discover-able. So you just keep one python process alive which keeps tracks what is on right now and what is off. Secondly in both cases that is `pyro` and `rpc` you do not use PID to find the service, services are discovered by name and port.

Comment: Actually, as I said this is not 24*7 server application. These are short-lived Batch Job processes. There are around 120k Batch job processes that start every day, completes its job and dies.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal I still do not understand. My solution is to instead deploying a supervisor (which needs to run 24*7) you create a simple script with which your batch jobs register when they start and send end signal when they die. Writing to file is much more troublesome and less reliable. Do you want to create 120k files or make them all write to the same file? Either case presents lots of unreliability

Comment: >> you create a simple script with which your batch jobs register when they start and send end signal when they die. Let's say Batch Job starts and registers itself, but then somehow it gets killed (maybe someone sends SIGKILL to it). In this case it won't be able to send a signal when it dies. One solution is to assume that it died if it didn't send any end signal in certain time interval but this can not always be true - for example if the job is taking too long to complete its task because of system load or something else.

Comment: And the other problem is Single Point of failure, that is if the supervisor is down then none of my Batch Jobs will be able to run or I will have to compromise on monitoring if supervisor goes down

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal If you look at my code example it doesn't matter if it sends the signal or not everything is handled in `except` block. That is timestamp of heartbeat is too old, batch job is unresponsive, batch job is dead etc. Of course you can have different exception to handle different cases. And no the batch jobs will start with or without the supervising script they could also check for it and run if it is down.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal Also from personal experience I can tell you that if 120k processes will start  writing to a file you are looking on some serious performance issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197081/discussion-between-lokesh-agrawal-and-mrangry777).

Comment: @mrangry777 the link to Pyro4's documention is deprecated. Can you replace it with the current up to date location http://pyro4.readthedocs.io/

Comment: @IrmendeJong Sure:)